# Submit button in a hyperlink

Tags: html, forms

I would have never thought that it was valid markup to put a `<input type="submit" />` in an anchor `<a>` like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Submit input in a hyperlink</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/form-submission" method="get">
        <a href="/hyperlink-click"><input type="submit" /></a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Oddly enough though, if you feed this into the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org), it validates.

What is supposed to happen when a user clicks on the submit button? Would this kind of setup just be unpredictable with different browsers doing whatever they please, or are there explicit rules dictating expected behavior? Would doing something like this ever come in handy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour isn't consistent between browsers.

[Milimetric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638468/submit-button-in-a-hyperlink#5639148) answer may be good for javascript, but consider what happens with unscripted html.

See the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PjtPZ/

Here I've just changed the html of the question so that the link navigates the page to www.microsoft.com and the form submits to www.google.com.

Click on the button in Firefox 4.0, IE9 or Opera 11 and the Google page is the one that appears. Do it in Chrome 10.0 or Safari 4.0 and you get the Microsoft page.

This is probably why it is disallowed in HTML5.

Comment: +1: Nice, I didn't even think to check that.  Now the question is, does jQuery normalize that behavior across browsers?  Is John Resig around? :)

Comment: @Milimetric - jQuery can't fix anything if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: @Richard - right, of course, I was continuing a train of thought from my answer (see my jsfiddle below).

Answer (score 3):

So here's the answer :)
It may not validate in HTML5, it may validate in HTML < 5, but I was still curious to see what happened.  It turns out it's pretty logical.  The button event fires first and then bubbles up to the link event.  Then the link event fires.  You can play with it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yEUM2/

It does the same thing in IE8, FF4, Chrome 10

Comment: good test, some additional propagation info [Javascript - Event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), first learned about this kinda thing with the jquery [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method on an event

Comment: Good test, but see the counter example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>In short, it isn't valid HTML.</strike>  It probably shouldn't be valid and, as Richard points out, it's interesting it's been addressed in HTML5

Try running the same code as HTML5. The HTML5 definition has corrected this by giving the error:

```
The element input must not appear as a descendant of the a element.
```

This is because you are displaying two buttons on the same place, so which button action should take preference? Essentially you're hiding one button action from the user, which is as good as having no second button at all.

There's more information on this in [HTML: The Markup Language Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.submit.html)

Comment: It validates though. It's interesting that they've addressed this issue in HTML5 though... but you're first point, that it isn't valid HTML, is incorrect.

Comment: I suppose it should still be considered valid, because if you padded the anchor then you would still be able to click it as well as the button inside.

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the guidelines, http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2, states that nested links are illegal, which the example could be seen as (just not added into the validator algorithm for XHTML)